# Whenever I try flutter run, it gives me the same error and I am not sure what to do

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first flutter project and I am trying to just run the example one that comes with it. I did `flutter run` in the correct directory and I started an emulator. I am not sure what to do to fix it. At first, there was a problem where it would get stuck at `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'` then I allowed studio.exe and studio64.exe to be allowed through the windows defender firewall.

Here is the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         
0.5s
[!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. 
Retrying the update...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: 
error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         
0.3s
[!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: First try `flutter upgrade` and `flutter clean` and if not solved, Open up the `android` directory which is located at flutter project root directory in Android Studio. There you can see gradle build and if fails why. And tell me what happend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few days ago I had a similar problem like this.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48159#issuecomment-571513079

Answer is from here, it solved my problem

> C:\Users\uejaz.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb
>   Move to this directory and delete gradle-5.6.2-all.zip and
>   gradle-5.6.2 folder
>
> Goto
>   https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip and
>   download the zip file Replace the .zip file with the one you had
>   deleted earlier and extract the folder "gradle-5.6.2" in the same
>   directory. I hope it will solve all your gradle-related problems.
>
> Note: if your gradle version is different than mine, just change the
>   version in the link provided above to download your gradle version.

Comment: I was doing what you suggested when I realized that originally, there was a zip file and a LCK file. There was no other folder. I deleted the zip file and the LCK file, is that what I was mean to do or was I meant to keep the LCK file? If I was meant to keep the LCK file, could I just take it from the recycling bin and put it into the correct directory?

Comment: It looks like it worked but now it is stuck in 'Running Gradle task 'assembleDebugger''. Do you know anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ops! you said **I am trying to just run the example one that comes with it**:

Those apps are implemented while ago. Please first try `flutter upgrade` and `flutter clean`.

If thats not worked check if `distributionUrl` is `http`. If so change it to `https`. Then do gradle build.

Your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file should be in flutter root project android directory. In my case it is `C:\flutter_app\android\gradle\wrapper`.

If this does not solved may be your gradle version in file system is broken. Deleting `cache` directory (`C:\Users\usernmae\.gradle\caches`) in .gradle and gradle build or sync from Android Studio will do the trick.