# Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download

Tags: flutter, gradle

```
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442718/whenever-i-try-flutter-run-it-gives-me-the-same-error-and-i-am-not-sure-what-to ?